# Trouble finding eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $ T $ be the matrix $$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        4 & -1 & 1 \\
        4 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 3 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$ I need to find the eigenvectors.

What I have done so far:

The Characteristic polynomial is $ (\lambda - 3)(\lambda -2)^2 $. So the eigenvalues are $ 2 $ and $ 3 $. I have found the eigenvector for $ \lambda = 3 $ but I'm having trouble finding the eigenvector for $ \lambda = 2 $.

$ \begin{pmatrix}
        -2 & 1 & -1 \\-4 & \ \ 2 & -1 \\ \ \ \  0 & \ \ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix} \left( \begin{array}{c} x \\ y \\ z \end{array} \right)$  $ = \left( \begin{array}{c} 2x \\ 2y \\ 2z \end{array} \right)$ which gives us the equations, $ 3z =0,-4x-z=0, -4x+y-z=0 $ so $ x=y=z=0 $. I'm trying to figure out where I went wrong.

Thanks in advance for any replies.

Edited once.

Comment: $(1,2)$-entry of $2I - T$.

Comment: That was stupid of me. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

To find eigenvectors, you should solve either the homogeneous equation $(\lambda I-T)\mathbf v=0$ or the equation $T\mathbf v=\lambda\mathbf v$. You appear to have combined the two and are trying to solve $(\lambda I-T)\mathbf v=\lambda\mathbf v$.

Answer (score 0):

were does 
$\begin{pmatrix}
        -2 & -1 & -1 \\-4 & \ \ 2 & -1 \\ \ \ \  0 & \ \ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix} \left( \begin{array}{c} x \\ y \\ z \end{array} \right) = \left( \begin{array}{c} 2x \\ 2y \\ 2z \end{array} \right)$
come from?

You can either say:
$\begin{pmatrix}
        -4 & -1 & 1 \\-4 & 0 & 1 \\   0 & 0 & -3 \end{pmatrix} \left( \begin{array}{c} x \\ y \\ z \end{array} \right) = \left( \begin{array}{c} 2x \\ 2y \\ 2z \end{array} \right)$

or you can say

$\begin{pmatrix}
        -2 & -1 & 1 \\-4 & -2 & 1 \\   0 & 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix} \left( \begin{array}{c} x \\ y \\ z \end{array} \right) = \mathbf 0$

I think the second one is easier to solve.